# Calendar view in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I am fetching a stored procedure to the report having two columns as date and non business day. I need to create a year wise calendar for the year which is getting fetched from stored procedure. Each page will have a calendar of a year with 12 months along with days.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this forum is for specific coding issues, not a place to just ask people to give you a solution with no effort on your part. If you explain with more detail and show what you have already tried, you will get a better response. Please see the following link.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I understand your concern but I am new to ssrs. I just got a requirement and am stuck. Could you please let me know what are the details you need apart from the things I have mentioned in the query. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would need a dataset with a Date (Day and Year at least) and a corresponding value for this Day. Then simply add a matrix in your report. For the columns textbox chose the Date (Day) and for the rows textbox chose the Date (Year). In the data textbox use your value. If you load it, it will look like calender because the Days get brocke down by Year.